# A bug in design while improving an edit on the same page

Tags: bug, design

When I tried to improve an edit on [a question page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74260/what-did-newt-offer-to-pay-gnarlack) in order to add a link, I just couldn't do it.

The possible reason behind was the Add Link pop-up was overlapped by the Edit Post pop-up.

Here is a screenshot of this.

[image]

I didn't find this bug on Stack Overflow.