# Text/image overlap in reopen vote review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just noticed a overlapping issue in the [Reopen Votes review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/64090):

[image]

Not sure if it's specific to Movies & TV Stackexchange or not but it didn't look right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Fix is waiting in repo and should be live in couple hours.

Comment: Meanwhile check [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/a-bug-in-design-while-improving-an-edit-on-the-same-page) too.